# add uniqueness constraint when there are already duplicate old records

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique-constraint

Say I have a table :employers and :employee. And I wanted to add the following:

```
ALTER TABLE employers ADD UNIQUE (employee_id);
```

This worked fine in development but since there are already duplicate records in production, it is not working in production.

Is there a way to add sequence number of uniqueness constraint, i.e. impose uniqueness constraint on only new records?

Comment: You need to delete the duplicates before you can create the constraint

Comment: The semantics of the question are vague. What should happen if a new record conficts with one or more old records?

Comment: if a new record conflicts with an old record, an uniqueness error will arise. I just don't want to mess up existing records that may have duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

Create a partial unique index

```
create unique index index_unique_employer_id on employers(employer_id)
where employer_id > 10
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createindex.html

Comment: This is usually a bad idea. It is far better to fix the duplicated data. You might find that there is code inserting the duplicates which could cause a problem on production. Especially if multiple different applications/imports insert data and each is designed differently. You might find that something does an insert rather than an update. Understanding what caused the duplicates amn knowing that you have fixed the cause is critical because if this is a unique field, then reports and exports are going to get into problems as well if you don't fix the bad data you currently have.

Comment: thanks! it is not feasible to fix duplicated data as they are valid. It is more like a change in business logic than bad data. In this way, will where employer_id > 10 be a good solution?